Error in importing GD&T information from STP model using STEPCAFControl_Reader
I use the STEPCAFControl_Reader interface of OCC to import a step format CAD file to parse the Datum, dimensions, and tolerances in the file. When loading tolerances, I use XCAFDocDimTolTool to build dimTolTool, and then use the GetGeomToleranceLabels and GetRefGeomToleranceLabels interface to obtain all tolerance labels. Then, I obtain the XCAFDomTolObjecties_GeomToleranceObject object inside. However, this object keeps getting 0 when obtaining tolerance values, but in other software (Geometric control x viewer) the value is valid. I don't know if it's a problem with the CAD file or the code I wrote. Does anyone have any information about this? Can you help me? Thank you.
TDF_LabelSequence aGDTs;
aDimTolTool->GetGeomToleranceLabels(mainLabel, aGDTs);
for (Standard_Integer j = 1; j <= aGDTs.Length(); j++)
{
    Handle(XCAFDoc_GeomTolerance) aDimTol;
    if (aGDTs.Value(j).FindAttribute(XCAFDoc_GeomTolerance::GetID(), aDimTol))
    {
        Handle(XCAFDimTolObjects_GeomToleranceObject) aDimTolObj = aDimTol->GetObject();
        auto type = aDimTolObj->GetType();
        // the value is always 0, but in other software the value is valid
        auto Value = aDimTolObj->GetValue();
    }
}
aGDTs.Clear();
aDimTolTool->GetGeomToleranceLabels(mainLabel, aGDTs);
for (Standard_Integer j = 1; j <= aGDTs.Length(); j++)
{
    Handle(XCAFDoc_GeomTolerance) aDimTol;
    if (aGDTs.Value(j).FindAttribute(XCAFDoc_GeomTolerance::GetID(), aDimTol))
    {
        Handle(XCAFDimTolObjects_GeomToleranceObject) aDimTolObj = aDimTol->GetObject();
        auto type = aDimTolObj->GetType();
        // the value is always 0, but in other software the value is valid
        auto Value = aDimTolObj->GetValue();
    }
}

I want to know why the STEPCAFControl_Reader of OCC always obtains a tolerance value of 0 when reading the tolerance information from the stp file. Is it a problem with my CAD model or the OCC interface?
